# Wordpress Whitescreen before login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with a WordPress website where I am getting a white screen on only specific pages (which seems to change randomly from time to time). I have noticed that after logging in to the WP-Admin account I am then able to view the pages with no issue. However swapping to another browser/computer that has not logged in still has the white-screen.

Here are some notes for things I have looked at.

1. Debugging is on, and there is no page related errors/etc.
2. I increased the memory just in case, should not be the issue.
3. Disabled all plugins.
4. Disabled the theme I was using and used a default instead.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the plugin called Sucuri, but I cannot confirm this and have tried disabling it. I am looking for any sort of troubleshooting I might be missing, or ideas on how to fix this.

**Edit** I should clarify, the pages change randomly but are consistent. E.g. currently a certain page is giving me a white screen, and its the only one. However last week it was my login page, and a month before that it was a separate page.

Comment: Have you tried checking the .htaccess file?

Comment: White screen - truly white screen - that is *intermittent* has been a memory issue (in my experience).  Sometimes you may not know how much you need to increase it - I have seen a site that needed 512MB before it would run properly.  So increasing memory may not have been enough.  Troubleshooting 101 on WP is to disable ALL plugins, then start re-enabling one at a time to determine the issue.

Comment: Expand your question with the *results* of each testing.  Are you saying that even with all plugins disabled, you would still get random white pages?

Comment: Results are negitive on all testing. Either no result or blank. E.g. no errors were generated, no changes, etc. As reference as my post mentions, I did disable all plugins with no change to the whitescreen pages.

Comment: @BradHouston I tried renaming them to old.htaccess to see if they were the cause. I don't have much experience with them, what would I be looking for?

Comment: I just had a brain wave! this happened to me! check your function.php for code errors.

Comment: @BradHouston I went ahead and verified the function.php (assuming function**s**.php). I even ran it through a couple of online parsers. I don't see any errors and the debug of it comes up clean. On an aside - the pages that were broken are now working again. I expect within the next little while (less then a week) another set of pages will start giving a white screen.